# onTableChange function in react-bootstrap-table-next always return undefined

Tags: react-bootstrap-table

I have quite compicated table in react-bootstrap-table-next wrapped in tookit provider. And I need to add onTableChange function. But console.log writes alaways undefined (checking, order by..)

I am missing something?

```
onTableChange(type, newState) {
    console.log(type);
    console.log(newState);
  }

   <ToolkitProvider
                    keyField="_id"
                    data={
                        this.state.data
                    }
                    columnToggle
                    columns={
                        this.state.columns
                    }

                    noDataIndication={() => <NoDataIndication />}>
                   <CustomToggleList {...props.columnToggleProps} />
                                <BootstrapTable {...props.baseProps}
                                    pagination={
                                        paginationFactory(options)
                                    }
                                    bordered={false}
                                    bootstrap4
                                    selectRow={selectRowProp}
                                    hover
                                    printable
                                    expandRow={this.props.id !== "LAST LOGIN EVENTS" ?
                                        expandRow : ""
                                    }
                                    onTableChange={this.onTableChange()}
                                    cellEdit={cellEditFactory({
                                        mode: 'click',
                                        blurToSave: true
                                    })}
 />
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
onTableChange={this.onTableChange()}
```

To this:

```
onTableChange={this.onTableChange}
```

Here this.onTableChange() you're calling the function without params so is undefined.